# ASP.NET Ajax - OnFailure - Get error text

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

i'm using MVC2, and am trying to display a friendly error message to the user, here is how:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
  Response.StatusCode = 403;

  return new ContentResult() { Content="frindly error"}
}
```

However, i'm having trouble to find how to read it on the ajax OnFailure callback:

```
function ajaxErrorHandler(context) {

// this fires an error, saying it's not a JSON object
    alert(context.get_response().get_object());


}
```

I can see in firebug that the response is correct.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
alert(context.get_data());
```

This will display "frindly error"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:
context.get_message() inside the onFailure callback...

function OnFailure(context) {
            alert(context.get_message());

```
    }
```

This has helped me.
-- Sudipto
www.supernovaservices.com